# JVM Embedded into C, does not appear under running programs

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a C program (working in Solaris SPARC), which is creating a JVM and calling a Java application via JNI.

The JVM is created and the java program works as expected, but I don't see the java process with `ps -ef | grep java` command.

Any idea about what could be the reason?

Comment: `java` is the name of the standard launcher. When you start JVM from *your program*, you should obviously see the name of *your process*, not `java`.

Comment: AIUI creating a JVM in C does not spawn a new process (unless you do the fork/exec dance), it simply runs it in-process, sharing address space and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@apangin and @the8472 are both correct, you will not find the `java` process anywhere, using `JNI_CreateJavaVM` you are embedding the JVM functionalities in your process.

I'll try to give evidence of this through references to the documentation (JNI is sparsely documented but i'll try).

From the [JNI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html):

> **Creating the VM**
>
> The `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` function loads and initializes a Java VM and returns a pointer to the JNI interface pointer. The thread that called `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` **is considered to be the main thread.**

And a few lines below:

> The attached thread should have enough stack space to perform a reasonable amount of work.

This confirms that a JVM instance lives in the same context that invoked the JNI's `createJavaVM` method, so no external dedicated process.